# HTML, CSS Header Assistance

Tags: css, html, scroll, position

Since i won't be able to post an image here's the link to it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxO1e.png

I have this website, the PHP and all other stuff are working. The problem is that when I scroll up to see other stuff below, the elements that get scrolled up goes over the header instead of going under. How do I solve this?

I can't seem to post the HTML in here, I tried the indent four spaces thing but it doesn't work with HTML stuff so instead here is the site: pageboost.comze.com

Here's the css for the main that is going over instead of under

```
.inmain
{
width:95%;
height:100%;
left:20px;
top:42px;
position:relative;
}
```

and here's the css for the header

```
.header
{
background-color:#ffd800;
width:100%;
height:42px;
position:fixed;
left:0px;
top:0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -6px black;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -6px black;
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to solve anything if you don't provide some code

Comment: you can post your code than you will get exact solution of your bug....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just define **z-index** value into your **Header** class or Id where you have defined the position.
It happens so when you will give the **z-index** value i hope that will work smoothly.....

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I have given the **z-index** value in **header class** its working fine now please check it.....

**HTML**

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="inmain">afdadfasf</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header
{
background-color:#ffd800;
width:100%;
height:42px;
position:fixed;
left:0px;
top:0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -6px black;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -6px black;
    z-index:1;
}

.inmain
{
width:95%;
height:100%;
left:20px;
top:35px;
position:relative;
}
```

for better understanding see the live demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/X8vpg/6/

Comment: Thanks guys! You've help me greatly ever since.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define **z-index** with one these positions `relative,absolute or fixed`.

For example write like his:

```
.header{
 position:fixed;
 z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! You've help me greatly ever since.